# HubSpot Messaging Library Close Button Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [HubSpot Messaging Library](http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/docs/welcome/) to display message.

I have used the following code:

```
var _notificatioMsg = "Message for display";

Messenger.options = {
    extraClasses: 'messenger-fixed messenger-on-bottom messenger-on-right',
    theme: 'air'
}

Messenger().post({
    message: _notificatioMsg,
    type: "success",
    showCloseButton: true,
    hideAfter: false
});
```

How do I trigger some code when when a user clicks on the close button.
Do I need to write Jquery `click event` for close button ?
I did not find any information  related to event for close button in Messaging Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom close action you can simply add a click event in the post hash:

```js
Messenger().post({
      message: _notificatioMsg,
      type: "success",
      showCloseButton: true,
      hideAfter: false
      events: {
          'click .messenger-close': function() {
             //the desired event
           }
      }
 });
```